# GUFW for console?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, ufw, gufw

I like the GUFW, but need something similar for console. I mean an interactive software without need to remember all the command line keys. Could you suggest one?

Answer (score 1):

In the [last version](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw#Use_Gufw_without_Graphical_Environment_or_Remote_Computer) you can use Gufw with a console in remote mode: